# A basic doubt on partial derivative and integrability

Tags: measure-theory

I want an example of a function $f(x,y): \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ such that for each $y$, $f(x,y)$ is integrable w.r.t $x$, but the partial derivative w.r.t $y$ is not integrable w.r.t $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ even.  Volterra's function serves as a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$.